# How to install git-lfs on WSL2?

Tags: git-lfs, wsl-2

```
fatal: 'lfs' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-lfs is broken?
```

Installing git-lfs on kali or ubuntu is simple, but steps are not easy to find. In my case it was because I needed it for git subrepo

```
This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can install git-lfs on WSL through your linux distribution's package manager. For example, in Debian or Ubuntu on WSL you would type:

1. `sudo apt-get install git-lfs`
2. `git lfs install`

[Readme](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation)

If you instead want to install git-lfs it on Windows directly:

1. Download the windows installer from [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases)
2. Run the windows installer
3. start a `command prompt`/or `git bash` for windows prompt and run `git lfs install`

Comment: Just to be clear, that's for installing on *Ubuntu* -- The directions would be the same for any Ubuntu user (not just WSL), and would be different if you were using a non-Ubuntu distribution on WSL.